# Why aren't Treasury bill auction reopenings marked as reopenings on the Treasury Auction Schedule?

Tags: united-states, government-bonds, treasury, auction

Let's consider on the 13-week bill whose auction date is Monday, March 13, 2023 on  [Treasury Tentative Auction Schedule](https://home.treasury.gov/system/files/221/Tentative-Auction-Schedule.pdf). It's not marked as a reopening on the Treasury Tentative Auction Schedule (no `R` in the reopening column):

[image]

However, on my broker's website, the 13-week bill seems to be a reopening, since it's actually a 52-week bill (CUSIP: `912796X53`):

[image]

Why aren't Treasury bill auction reopenings marked as reopenings on the Treasury Auction Schedule? I feel I may have misunderstood something.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144591/discussion-on-question-by-franck-dernoncourt-why-arent-treasury-bill-auction-re); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion *will* be removed.

Answer (score 4):

As linked to by @littleadv, Treasury Bills aren't reopened.

From the

**Federal Registry July 28, 2004, Part IV, Department of the Treasury, Fiscal Service, 31 CFR Part 356
Sale and Issue of Marketable Book-Entry
Treasury Bills, Notes, and Bonds—Plain
Language Uniform Offering Circular; Final
Rule**

https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/FR-2004-07-28/pdf/04-17012.pdf

> **§ 356.5 What types of securities does the
> Treasury auction?**
>
> We offer securities under this part
> exclusively in book-entry form and as
> direct obligations of the United States
> issued under Chapter 31 of Title 31 of
> the United States Code. The securities
> are subject to the terms and conditions
> in this part, the regulations governing
> book-entry Treasury bills, notes, and
> bonds (31 CFR Part 357), and the
> auction announcements. **When we issue
> additional securities with the same
> CUSIP number as outstanding
> securities, we consider them to be the
> same securities as the outstanding
> securities.**
>
> (a) Treasury bills.
>
> (1) Are issued at a discount;
>
> (2) Are redeemed at their par amount
> at maturity; and
>
> (3) Have maturities of not more than
> one year.
>
> ...

So what is going on with the CUSIP?

Checking the Treasury Direct site:
https://www.treasurydirect.gov/auctions/auction-query/?cusip=912796X53

The CUSIP `912796X53` as of EOD 2023-03-13 has 3 Bills with the same maturity date:

| CUSIP | Security Type | Security Term | Auction Date | Issue Date | Maturity Date | Price per $100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 912796X53 | Bill | 13-Week | 03/13/2023 | 03/16/2023 | 06/15/2023 | 98.799306 |
| 912796X53 | Bill | 26-Week | 12/12/2022 | 12/15/2022 | 06/15/2023 | 97.659278 |
| 912796X53 | Bill | 52-Week | 06/14/2022 | 06/16/2022 | 06/15/2023 | 96.946444 |

As all Bills are issued at discount to par, it may be better to think of the CUSIP as marking the maturity date for all short term Treasury Bill/auction/non-auction obligations which are due on that date.

Logically if you transacted on a $10,000 USD 52-week Bill maturing on 06/15/2023 at the same date/time as the auction for the 13-week Bill maturing on 06/15/2023, the par value of $10,000 USD doesn't change, only the price/discount value would change matching the 13-week Bill auction discount. The seller capturing the increase in price from the original 52-week Bill issue date.

Answer (score 2):

Treasury bills have no reopenings. See [here](https://www.treasurydirect.gov/auctions/when-auctions-happen/schedule-auction-reopenings/):

> Note: Bills have no reopenings. Instead, when needed, we auction short-term Cash Management Bills. (See the page about Bills).

Edit: your brokerage doesn't seem to say that this is a reopening, so I'm not sure why you even thought that.

You cannot participate in the Treasury offering of CMBs, they're only open for institutional investors. By the time they hit the secondary market - they're indistinguishable from any other treasury with the same maturity date (hence the same CUSIP).

Comment: The comments have gotten out of control and have been removed. Further comments on the answer will be removed with no warning.